# Store only one instance of an element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writting a Java method that stores words read in from a file in an ArrayList, but only one instance of each  should be stored in the ArrayList.

So what kind of algorithm is best fitted for this?

Also, the ArrayList is already created in a different method.

Comment: Any reason you want to use an `ArrayList` rather than a `Set` of some kind?

Comment: Use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).  If you want to preserve the order, then use the `ArrayList` but also use a `Set` to keep track of which words have already been added.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order but avoid duplicates, a `SortedSet` is a better choice than a `Set` and `ArrayList` combo. It's what it is designed for.

Comment: You can also use a `LinkedHashSet` to preserve insertion order but not create duplicates.

Comment: I have to use ArrayList by the boss's request.

Comment: If your boss is insisting that it eventually end up in the `ArrayList`, copy it all in there at the end. If he's insisting that you add it line by line into the `ArrayList` without any other data structures, you probably should get a new boss.

Comment: If I were asked to do this, I'd create a million-line file, and wire some code that read it into an `ArrayList` and checked for duplicates with `.contains()`, and some other code that used a `SortedSet`, and then show my boss the running times of the two versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an ArrayList and you must use it, you can use the contains method to validate if the word you are trying to store is already in your list, if its not, then add it:

```
if(!arrayList.contains("yourWord")){
    arrayList.add("yourWord");
}
```

Or, just use a Set and then convert it to your ArrayList.

Comment: Well, I haven't leaned that so far, are they any other methods?

Comment: Really, don't do this, though. It's very  inefficient. If you have a large file, you'll notice it in a big way. You'd be better off reading everything into a `SortedSet` and then adding the contents of that into your `ArrayList`, if that's where it must end up.

Comment: @chiastic-security Well, he has to use an ArrayList by request, I'm just asking what he wants, if it was my choice I would do it in another way.